# MYSQL count hours passed exluding weekends

Tags: mysql, datetime, mysql-function

I've come to a halt, I made a funtion inside mysql counting hours but it keeps giving me faulty numbers, I've been looking at it for hours and I just can't see what I am doing wrong

```
FUNCTION `WorkingHours`(`stardate` TIMESTAMP, `enddate` TIMESTAMP) RETURNS int(11)
BEGIN
DECLARE result DECIMAL(20,10) DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE TotWeeks DECIMAL(20,10);
DECLARE FullWeeks INT;
DECLARE RestDays DECIMAL(20,10);
DECLARE StartDay INT DEFAULT WEEKDAY(stardate) + 1;
SET TotWeeks = (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,stardate,enddate))/(24*7);
SET FullWeeks = FLOOR(TotWeeks);
SET RestDays = ROUND((TotWeeks-FullWeeks) * 7);
IF(RestDays + StartDay) > 5 THEN SET result = ROUND((TotWeeks*7*24) - (FullWeeks*2*24 + (((RestDays + StartDay) - 5) * 24)));
ELSE SET result = ROUND((TotWeeks*7*24) - (FullWeeks*2*24));
END IF;
RETURN result;
END
```

if anyone got any suggestions or an alternative approach I am more than willingly happy to replace this one.

```
Startdate:2017-07-05 12:17:18
Enddate:2017-07-07 18:30:42
```

Gives me -**5**

**Edit:**
these dates gives -45

```
Startdate:2017-07-09 13:55:41
Enddate:2017-07-10 17:31:56
```

the function works almost everytime expect for the few times it doesn't and I jsut cant figure out why

Comment: I'm guessing that `stardate` is a parameter, but could that possibly be named `startdate` instead?

Comment: Yes its a parameter, updated the code to show the entire function for clearity

Comment: hahahha oh you were thinking about the misspelling there =P yeah I'll correct it, thank you for mentioning

Comment: Misspelling ok, as long it was used the same way throughout the handling, so no big deal. :-)

Comment: I ran your function as-is, and I get: 54 ... `WorkingHours('2017-07-05 12:17:18','2017-07-07 18:30:42')` returned `54` for me, which is about right 2 days (48hrs) + about 6hrs to be 54.

Comment: Also, I changed the end date to `2017-07-09` (to include the weekend), and still get 54. How are you calling/using the function?

Comment: @PaulT. I'm using it inside a query like so `WorkingHours(post_modified,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)`

Comment: Same here, I basically did a `SELECT WorkingHours('2017-07-05 12:17:18','2017-07-07 18:30:42'` to try your function.  What is an example value of `post_modified`? Perhaps that value may need a conversion?

Comment: that column is a timestamp, I guess current_timestamp has to be the function here acting strange, im running this code on a little older mysql has to be that.

Comment: Ok, I just tried with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and the result was different. I get 49, expecting more than the earlier 54, so there might be a slight mishandling in the function. What mysql version do you have?

Comment: nope wasn't current time stamp,

try these dates and you'll get -45
`
SET @p0 =  '2017-07-09 13:55:41';

SET @p1 =  '2017-07-10 17:31:56';
SELECT  `WorkingHours` (
@p0 , @p1
) AS  `WorkingHours` ;
`

Comment: I ran this query to check some of the function calculations for those dates: `select WEEKDAY('2017-07-09 13:55:41') + 1 as 'StartDay', (TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2017-07-09 13:55:41','2017-07-10 17:31:56'))/(24*7) as 'TotWeeks', ROUND((((TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2017-07-09 13:55:41','2017-07-10 17:31:56'))/(24*7))-FLOOR((TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2017-07-09 13:55:41','2017-07-10 17:31:56'))/(24*7))) * 7) as 'RestDays', ROUND((0.1607*7*24) - (0*2*24 + (((1 + 7) - 5) * 24))) as 'IF calc' ` ... Give that a run to see the output, I'm running out of space for this comment. The 'If calc': uses the 1st 3 col. values

Comment: @PaulT. Yeah the fault is withing the logic inside the if statment, the problem occurs because im substracting to much from the total, I just can't figure out how I'm gonna take weekends into account with a general statment

Comment: There's likely a way, I'm sure. I'll check into alternatives, but I won't know until later today, or more likely, tomorrow. (If I get anywhere with my attempt)

Comment: A question on the 'working hours'... are you looking for 8 hrs, per day, for business days only (for example, one shift), or are there 3 shifts for each business day?  I'm not clear 100% clear about hours calculation that you need? ... Also, what about holidays, is this a factor to be considered as well?

Comment: nope no need to take holidays into account or shifts, it's simply 24hours for everyday just want to exclude weekends thats all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I crossed a function that does what you need. It simply counts weekdays for a date range.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION `CountWeekDays` (sdate VARCHAR(50), edate VARCHAR(50)) RETURNS INT

BEGIN
    #  first some variables for our procedure/function...
    DECLARE wdays, tdiff, counter, thisday smallint;
    DECLARE newdate DATE;
    #  now loop from start to end counting the loops and the number of weekdays...

    SET newdate := sdate;
    SET wdays = 0;

    #  return 1 if they're the same for "same day service"...
    if DATEDIFF(edate, sdate) = 0 THEN RETURN 1; END IF;
    #  if they're negative, return zero...
    if DATEDIFF(edate, sdate) < 0 THEN RETURN 0; END IF;

    label1: LOOP
        SET thisday = DAYOFWEEK(newdate);
        IF thisday BETWEEN 2 AND 6 THEN SET wdays := wdays + 1; END IF;
        SET newdate = DATE_ADD(newdate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
        IF DATEDIFF(edate, newdate) < 0 THEN LEAVE label1; END IF;
    END LOOP label1;

    RETURN wdays;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

I found that function [here](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,240209,241449#msg-241449).

Then to use it, here are a few example runs. Note that the time-portion really doesn't matter, as the function uses the date-portion.

```
select CountWeekDays('2017-07-05', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) * 24 as WorkingHours
```

[image]

```
select CountWeekDays('2017-07-09 13:55:41', '2017-07-10 17:31:56') * 24 as WorkingHours
```

[image]

```
select CountWeekDays('2017-07-05', '2017-07-07') * 24 as WorkingHours
```

[image]

```
select CountWeekDays('2017-07-08', '2017-07-09') * 24 as WorkingHours
```

[image]

```
select CountWeekDays('2017-07-07', '2017-07-10') * 24 as WorkingHours
```

[image]

So try it out and see what you think. You can remove the `* 24` portion of the query to see the weekday count for any given date range.

Comment: Using your code I made a final function that counts hours beetween 2 dates excluding weekends, it's pretty precise

https://pastebin.com/HPxuBsaj